# i need to remove same elements from list in c

Tags: c, list, linked-list

someone can end this algoritm?

```
void trinti_pasikartojancius(struct el * *prad, struct el * *pab, struct el * elem){
    struct el *g, *elemk;
    int i =1;
    g = *prad;
    elem= elem->kitas;
        if(g->duom == elem->duom){
            elem->kitas->pries = elem->pries;
            elem->pries->kitas = elem->kitas;
            free(elem);
            if( g->kitas != NULL){
                g = g->kitas;
                g->pries = NULL;
                free( *prad );
                *prad = g;
            }
            else{
                free ( *prad );
                *prad = NULL;
                *pab = NULL;
            }
        }
}
```

*(Translated variable names to English, via Google Translate.  I believe the question was meant to be "Can someone **complete** this algorithm?")*

```
void delete_duplicate (struct e ** start, struct ** e end, struct elem * e) {
    struct e * g * elemk;
    int i = 1;
    g = * start;
    elem = elem-> next;
        if (g-> conn == elem-> data) {
            elem-> next-> v = elem-> before;
            elem-> v-> next = elem-> next;
            free (items);
            if (g-> next! = NULL) {
                g = g-> next;
                g-> before = NULL;
                free (* start);
                * start = g;
            }
            else {
                free (* start);
                * start = NULL;
                * end = NULL;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: What is the context ? What is blocking ? Why are variables names opaques ?

Comment: OP: I suggest you change the variable names from Lithuanian to English, for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming (as Google tells me) that *pries* and *kitas* are Lithuanian for "previous" and "next," then we have a doubly-linked list, and I guess we're removing an element.

The problem appears to be that you don't have a loop around your `if`/`else`.  As your program is written, without the loop, `g->duom == elem->duom` can't be true unless `prad` (start) is `elem`.

But since you already know the node to remove (`elem`), why look for it?  Start with this:

```
elem->kitas->pries = elem->pries;
elem->pries->kitas = elem->kitas;
free(elem);
```

This removes `elem` from whatever list it's in.

But, you might also have two conditions to watch for.  `elem` could be the beginning of the list (`prad`) or the end of the list (`pab`) or both.  So, if those are important (sometimes they are not), check for them separately.

If you want/need to be paranoid, you should also loop through the list (exactly like a search routine, which I assume you already have written) to make sure that `prad`, `pab`, and `elem` are all part of the same list.

If you need a more complete guide through the process, there is a [full sample program](http://www.thelearningpoint.net/computer-science/data-structures-doubly-linked-list-with-c-program-source-code) available with every list operation implemented.  It may not work for your application, but will at least point the way forward if you get lost.

**Edit**:  Having gone deeper in depth on the translation attempt, I now see what's going on.  Deleting duplicates of the `elem` parameter makes much more sense.

My second paragraph is the important one.  You need a loop.  The code you produced even has *space* for a loop, where the indentation seems strange.  It should look something like:

```
while (g != NULL) {
    /* Your existing, indented code here */
    g = g->kitas;
}
```